# stylePreprocessorOptions not working on @Angular/cli 7

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

So, I'm trying to 'whitelabelyze' my app allowing multiple options of designs for multiple clients. And inside my component's scss I need to load a '_variables.scss' that would be under this 'themes' folder, the structure is like this:

```
/
- themes
-- client-1
--- _variables.scss
-- client-2
--- _variables.scss
```

And inside my angular.json, I have this config:

```
"projects": {
  "client-1": {
     ...
     "architect": {
       "build": {
         ...
         "options": {
           ...
           "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
             "includePaths": [
               "themes/client-1"
             ]
           },
           "styles": [
             "src/styles.scss",
           ]
           ...
         }
         ...
       }
     },

     "client-2": {
     ...
     "architect": {
       "build": {
         ...
         "options": {
           ...
           "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
             "includePaths": [
               "themes/client-2"
             ]
           },
           "styles": [
             "src/styles.scss",
           ]
           ...
         }
         ...
       }
     }
  }
```

According with the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L594), I'm doing it right, but my scss files are not loading the file 'variables' correctly. This is the import on my scss files:

```
@import "variables";
```

This is the error that happens:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

@import "variables";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: variables.
      in /Users/erick/Projects/sample-project/src/styles.scss (line 2, column 1)
```

Any suggestions how to approach here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the problem.

I was loading `themes/client-X` instead of `src/themes/client-X` inside the `angular.json`.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when running tests, the solution was to add the same style `stylePreprocessorOptions` to the test configuration in angular.json as well as the build configuration

Comment: I was searching for solution since long time. My prod bundle was getting compiled successfully. It was just jasmine test that were failing. Following your approach fixed that for me. Thanks Simons